# Get string after character

Tags: string, bash, extract

I have a string that looks like this:

```
 GenFiltEff=7.092200e-01
```

Using bash, I would like to just get the number after the `=` character. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This should be reopened. `How to grep` is asking how you do it with grep, this question is asking how to get string after character... not tied with `grep`.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

For the text after the first `=` and before the next `=`

```
cut -d "=" -f2 <<< "$your_str"
```

or

```
sed -e 's#.*=\(\)#\1#' <<< "$your_str"
```

For all text after the first `=` regardless of if there are multiple `=`

```
cut -d "=" -f2- <<< "$your_str"
```

Comment: Good for simple cases, however these methods don't play well when there is more than one "=" in the string. Chepner's first solution is simple and more reliable.

Comment: The answer is more useful when using | to run commands in a chain then when using variables.

Comment: This works perfectly for: `./download/file.php?id=65508` where I need everything after the `?`.  +1     NOTE: Chepner's solution(s) **did not** work in this case.

Answer (score 173):

Use parameter expansion, if the value is already stored in a variable.

```
$ str="GenFiltEff=7.092200e-01"
$ value=${str#*=}
```

Or use `read`

```
$ IFS="=" read name value <<< "GenFiltEff=7.092200e-01"
```

Either way,

```
$ echo $value
7.092200e-01
```

Comment: If the string has more than one "=": 
`${str##*=} to get from the last match.
${str#*=} to get from the first match. 
${str%%=*} to get until the first match.
${str%=*} to get until the last match.`
[String Manipulation @ tldp.org] (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: I didnt get the second solution to work: 
`$ IFS="=" read name value <<< "GenFiltEff=7.092200e-01"`
using bash 4.4.5

Comment: Works fine for me in 4.4.5. If you cannot figure out the problem, though, please open a new question that includes the result you *do* get.

Comment: It would be great if this answer explained itself in more detail. What exactly do each of `#*=` do here?

Comment: The `#` operator omits the shortest prefix that matches the pattern `*=` from the expansion of `$str`.

Comment: For `./download/file.php?id=65508`, I need everything after the `?`. Unfortunately, neither solution works. And yes - I changed the `=` to `?`.  Regrettably, -1.

Comment: What exactly did you try? `?` is subject to pattern matching just like `*`.

Answer (score 26):

```
echo "GenFiltEff=7.092200e-01" | cut -d "=" -f2
```

Comment: Note that you can add `-s` flag to display nothing if the delimiter was not present

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
your_str='GenFiltEff=7.092200e-01'
echo $your_str | cut -d "=" -f2
```

Answer (score 5):

```
${word:$(expr index "$word" "="):1}
```

that gets the `7`.  Assuming you mean the entire rest of the string, just leave off the `:1`.

Comment: `$value = ${word:$(expr index "$word" "=")}` worked well for me to return everything after the equal sign.