# How do I get value of variable from file using shell script?

Tags: shell, grep, configuration-files, ini

There is a file `post_check.ini` I need the value set for:

```
Max_value=2
```

How would I get the value `2` from `Max_value`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash get string after character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148796/bash-get-string-after-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
grep -Po '(?<=Max_value=).*' post_check.ini
```

Comment: This one works with one change of, I added the awk '{print $1}' to get first part else it would return whole line.
But what if I want to set back the value I got 

value=$(grep -Po '(?<=Max_value=).*' /usr/post_check.ini|awk '{print $1}')
sed -i -r 's/Max_value=[0-9]+/Max_value=0/g' /usr/master.ini
echo "$value"
sed -i -r 's/Max_value=[0-9]+/Max_value=$value/g' /usr/master.ini
value=$(grep -Po '(?<=Max_value=).*' /usr/master.ini|awk '{print $1}')
echo "$value"

If I reset it to zero and try to set it back to old value How would I do that ?

Comment: @JumpOffBox grep can only extract data. cannot set data. you may need awk/sed to do that. But that would be another new question. You could open a new question. Please don't write big block code in comment, it is hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
Max_value=$(sed -n '/^Max_value=\([0-9]*\)$/s//\1/p' post_check.ini)
```

Comment: Points for the use of an empty pattern after `s` but maybe simply `'s/^Max_value=//p'` would be easier to type and comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using crudini which is a dedicated tool to manipulate ini files from shell

```
value=$(crudini --get /usr/post_check.ini section Max_value)
```

Details on usage and download at:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/

Answer (score 0):

You might find it useful to use proper config file parser. Given the following `.ini` file:

```
$ cat post_check.ini
[section 1]
Max_value=123
[section 2]
Max_value=456
```

The following `python` script will print `123`:

```
import ConfigParser, os
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('post_check.ini')
print config.get('section 1','Max_value')
```

This is most reliable and modifiable way to go if you need to work with config files.