# sed command to retrieve port number

Tags: regex, sed

Can you please help me with a `sed` command to retrieve '9034' value from these JVM arguments.

```
-OtherJVM1=value1 -OtherJVM2=value2 -Dserver.port=9034 -Dajp.port=8534
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*\(Dserver.port=\)//p'
```

The above sed command is giving:

```
9034 -Dajp.port=8534
```

But I only want '9034', within 1 command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash get string after character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148796/bash-get-string-after-character)

Comment: @DevOpsNewB, With `grep` :  `grep -oP '(?<=-Dserver.port=)[0-9]*' <<< 'input-string'`

Comment: Is it complete command? looks like there is syntax issues

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple sed command

```
sed 's/.*Dserver.port=\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/'  <<< "-OtherJVM1=value1 -OtherJVM2=value2 -Dserver.port=9034 -Dajp.port=8534"
```

Comment: The above sed  does not work. its giving back the entire string

Comment: which `sed` version your are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SED, but if instead of a "`.`" (dot) in your regex you use a `\d`, it should match any number of digits after `Dserver.port=`, without capturing the rest of the string.