# Linux bash - extract value from grep output

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have variable `$OUTPUT=abc PHYSIN=lalala ghi`

How can I extract the value of `PHYSIN` into another new variable called `VETH_NAME`,
in other words, I'd like `VETH_NAME` to be `lalala`

How can I do so using bash commands?

Thanks

Comment: Please format your question and show a [mcve] so it is clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is what you are saying :

```
OUTPUT="abc"
PHYSIN="lalala ghi"


VETH_NAME=$(echo "$PHYSIN" | cut -d" " -f1)
```

finally :

```
echo $VETH_NAME
```

lalala

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter expansion with the `%%` operator, which drops the longest matching suffix from the expansion.

```
OUTPUT=abc
PHYSIN="lalala ghi"

VETH_NAME=${PHYSIN%% *}
```

Comment: I notice this is basically identical to your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148796/bash-get-string-after-character - perhaps you'd like to review [the Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](//stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) where we have collected a number of common FAQs. Obviously, if you'd like to help us maintain, organize, and develop this resource, you're most welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried; I link to some of the questions frequently, but don't pretend to memorize all the links on that page. Questions like this are far faster to whip out an answer than to search for a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, it's a struggle. But thanks for following up; just wanted to make sure you are aware. There's a link to a chat room down at the end if you'd like to participate at some later time. Cheers!