# Parse .env file with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have .env file and I am trying to parse the value from it.

I ran this

`cat .env | grep PORT=`

I got

`PORT=3333`

How do I grab the value of a specific key?

Comment: Use 'cut' command

Comment: Assign the output to a variable, and then use a [Parameter Expansion operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to get the part after `=`.

Comment: I don't want to change anything, I just want to read from it.

Comment: I never said anything about changing anything.

Comment: `line=$(grep PORT= .env)` and then get the part of `$line` after `=`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep for contents AFTER pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10358547/608639), [Get string after character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15148796/608639), [cut for key-value pairs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/186453/56041), [Extract values from key-value pair and output values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321883/56041), etc.

Answer (score 7):

```
cat env | grep PORT= | cut -d '=' -f2
```

Comment: `grep PORT= <env` or `grep PORT= env` is more efficient than using a separate `cat` process.

Comment: You are right! 
There are several ways to do this. I presented one of those.

Comment: Sure -- but if you're going to present one way, why not try to optimize for a best-practice approach? The extra `cat` doesn't matter much in this specific case, but it's a bad habit to get people in -- `cat foo | wc -c` stops `wc` from being able to just use `seek()` and `tell()` to get the size of its input file in constant time, f/e, so the impact can be much larger in other commands. (Similarly, GNU `sort` can parallelize on large input files... but only when reading from a seekable file, not from a FIFO, which can only be read a single time, front-to-back).

Comment: I was looking for something like this to parse `/etc/os-release` for `ID`, and this returned the value of `VERSION_ID`. grepping for `^ID` fixed that for me.

Answer (score 4):

Let say your input looks like this :

```
$ cat test.txt
Port=2020
Email=me@myserver.com
Version=2.02
```

Then this will do :

```
awk -F'=' '/^Version/ { print $2}'  test.txt
```

#### Output

```
2.02
```

Comment: Good answer. You might actually show the command substitution necessary to use this (`version=$(awk ...)`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval` to parse the assignment line, later variable values can be substituted with `$`:

```
eval "$(grep ^PORT= .env)"
echo $PORT
```

Comment: This is going to change the environment of the whole script, possibly including things like `PATH`.

Comment: I don't want to change anything, I just want to read from it.

Comment: `grep ^PORT= .env > tmp.sh`, `source tmp.sh`

Comment: At that point you could `eval "$(grep ^PORT= .env)"` and avoid the temporary file. That way, also, you avoid the vulnerability to a symlink attack from using a hardcoded tempfile name. (Still vulnerable to a `PORT=$(rm -rf ~)` config file, of course).

Comment: I've edited the answer to use eval on the single grep'ed line with the desired variable.

Comment: `eval $foo` is less reliable than `eval "$foo"` (as it isn't a syntactic element that suppresses string-splitting, its arguments get string-split, glob-expanded, and then joined back together into a string) -- and backticks for command substitution are considered legacy syntax (hard to nest, and backslashes have a different meaning within them than outside). Please consider the syntax I suggested in the comment above.

Comment: Run `foo=$'printf \'%s\n\' "hello world" "goodbye world"'`, and then compare `eval $foo` and `eval "$foo"` for an example. And that's a relatively tame one; it's easy to expand local filenames into your code if the content being evaluated has a wildcard with whitespace on both ends, f/e.