# Get git branch name without prefix

Tags: git, git-branch

I have these branches:

```
refs/heads/master
refs/heads/feature/dummy
```

Is there native git command to get only the last part of branch name? (`master`, `dummy` in the above example)

I have tried `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` but will get `master` and `feature/dummy`

Comment: There is no branch named `dummy` in the list you posted. The name of the second branch is `feature/dummy`. Git cannot identify it if you use only `dummy`. Try to run `git checkout dummy` and it will fail.

Comment: The branch you are currently on _**is**_ `feature/dummy`

Comment: @axiac, @evolutionxbox yes, I know I am on feature/dummy. What I want is a git command to get `dummy`, not `feature/dummy`. This is because I have further processing that will not work with the forward slash

Comment: Why do you need 'dummy'? If you know what the prefix is, you can filter it out using something like grep.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have a analysis on `SonarQube` which will automatically strip the `feature/` part of the branchname. I'll then have some code to hit Sonar's API to get analysis result, I'll need to pass in the short branchname as a param. But yeah, I can try `grep` or tokenize, I just want to know if there is a native git command

Comment: I wouldn't think so, because there is no need in git. Why does SonarQube strip that part out?

Comment: How about `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | xargs basename`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox not sure, their API's param `branch` only accepts the last part

Comment: @hydradon honestly, it sounds like an issue with SonarQube...

Comment: @Jubobs sorry, forgot to mention that I want a `Command Line` syntax, `xargs` doesn't work :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I want a Command Line syntax"... Do you mean that you want to use Git commands alone, and no other Unix utility? Anyway, I tested the command in a local repo and it works as desired, both for `master` and `feature/dummy`.

Comment: @Jubobs I mean the Command Line in Windows, not Unix, as this will be executed on my team's Windows build agent :) Anyway I think I'll tokenize it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there isn't one, simply because git allows forward slashes in branch names. Take a look at [git-branch docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) to see how the `branchname` is defined:
[image]
Further more, take a look at the [git-check-ref-format docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) to understand how can you restrict this, if need be (`--allow-onelevel`).

With all that in mind, I think git sees the branch name as a whole, including the slash, so it wouldn't need to provide any specific command to parse it, but you can always pipe the branch name to another tool that will filter it out. For example [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15149278/2428861) addresses such case. You would probably have to use something like: `value=${str#*/}`.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will need to pipe or tokenize the branch name to get the last part

Answer (score 2):

The following also seems to work:

```
$ git name-rev --name-only refs/heads/master
master
```

This appears to be very similar to the `rev-parse` solution you proposed yourself.  It also appears to work on hashes, e.g. where `b51e7569` is the commit pointed to by `master`:

```
$ git name-rev --name-only b51e7569
master
```

Comment: Thanks `git name-rev --name-only HEAD` did the trick.