# How to get the substring after cetain char, and if the char doesn't exist, return empty

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string

```
VAR_A="127.0.0.1:12345"
```

I want to split it into `HOSTNAME` and `PORT`, with the delimiter `:`.

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15149278/10400141), I'm using this syntax to split the original `VAR_A` string:

```
HOSTNAME=${VAR_A%%:*}
PORT=${VAR_A#*:}
```

And it works if `VAR_A` if of the form `xxxx:xxxx`.

But I'd like to have the following result according to the value passed to `VAR_A`:

- If `VAR_A` doesn't contain the char `:`, e.g. `VAR_A=127.0.0.1`, then `HOSTNAME` is assigned with `127.0.0.1`, and assign empty string to `PORT`
- If `VAR_A` contains the char `:` but nothing is after that `:`, e.g. `VAR_A=127.0.0.1:`, then same, `HOSTNAME` is assigned with `127.0.0.1`, and assign empty string to `PORT`
- If `VAR_A` contains the char `:` but nothing before that `:`, e.g. `VAR_A=:12345`, then assign empty string to `HOSTNAME`, and `12345` to `PORT`.

With current codes, if `VAR_A=127.0.0.1`, I got both `HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1` and `PORT=127.0.0.1`, which is not desired.

If doable, I'd prefer a syntax similar to the one I provided -- the more succint/elegant the better.

Comment: Note: Bash and POSIX shell are two completely different shells. Since bash is included, presumably that is what is wanted. With POSIX shell you would want to use a utility like `awk` or `sed` (or perhaps `grep`). With bash, it has built-ins that will handle the parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a `regex` solution:

```
list=(127.0.0.1:12345 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1: :12345)
for VAR_A in "${list[@]}"; do
    if [[ $VAR_A =~ ^([0-9.]*):?([0-9]*)$ ]]; then
        HOSTNAME=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; PORT=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        printf "%-16s HOSTNAME=%-10s PORT=%-10s\n" "$VAR_A" "$HOSTNAME" "$PORT"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1:12345  HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1  PORT=12345
127.0.0.1        HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1  PORT=
127.0.0.1:       HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1  PORT=
:12345           HOSTNAME=           PORT=12345
```

Explanation of the regex `^([0-9.]*):?([0-9]*)$`:

- `^([0-9.]*)` matches a zero or more length sequence of digits and/or dots
  at the beginning of `$VAR_A`.
  The matched substring is captured with `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.
  The regex doesn't strictly validate the ipv4 address  but will be
  enough for the purpose.
- `:?` matches zero or one colon character.
- `([0-9]*)$` matches a zero or more length sequence of digits at the
  end of `$VAR_A`. The matched substring is captured with `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the first part with another parameter expansion:

```
VAR_A=127.0.0.1

HOSTNAME=${VAR_A%%:*}
PORT=${VAR_A#"$HOSTNAME"}
PORT=${PORT#:}
```

If there is no newline in VAR_A:

```
IFS=: read -r HOSTNAME PORT <<< "$VAR_A"
```

Comment: You can shorten it with `PORT=${VAR_A#"$HOSTNAME:"}`

Answer (score -1):

If this is for a bash script, you can use `if..else` statements just like any other programming language.

I'd recommend checking out [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-check-if-string-contains-substring-in-bash/) tutorial page and creating some type of script that first checks to see if your string has the `:` character, then performing further actions as needed (e.g. parsing the left/right halves as needed for the HOST and PORT).

This is just one approach, of course; there are plenty other ways to do this.

Comment: This does not answer to the question.